# Observing changes to variable

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have a variable that is used in more than one place (a user). I don't want to get that info every time I open a fragment or activity, less network traffic.

What I'm thinking about is getting this data once, and observing it in the other places.

I understand there are such things as Observables and Eventbuses, I've looked into RxJava2 and I can't seem to find a way to update the value held by the Observable.

Can you tell me what I should be doing? I'd also like to see if there is a way to re-update the data every while (for example, every 1 second).

Comment: One thing should be, taking `Observable` at **Application level** class. so that, it can be shared everywhere as simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it as below:

You can fetch your data from network in a `Repository` class and make this class singleton. Then retrieve data from service and send it to a `LiveData` object. 
Now you can observe this `LiveData` object and the method that retrieves data from service separately. So once you retrieve data, you will have it for future use and if you want to retrieve data from service again, you can call the retrieve method and observe it.

Similar to below code:

(NOTE: this code is just a sample and it doesn't necessary compile as I don't know your models.)

```
 DataRepository {

    private static DataRepository instance;
    private final LiveData<User> userLiveData;

    private DataRepository() {}

    public synchronized static DataRepository getInstance(){
        synchronized (DataRepository.class) {
           if(instance == null){
               instance = new DataRepository();
               instance.userLiveData = new MutableLiveData();
           }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public LiveData<User> getUser(){             
         return userLiveData;
    }

    public LiveData<User> fetchUser(){
         callGetUserServiceAsync();
         return userLiveData;
    }

    public void callGetUserServiceAsync(){
        //call your service asynchronously and when service call back is called do as below, this call sample is in retrofit format, yours might be different
        callService().enqueue( new CallBack<User>(){

               @Override
               public void onResponse(Call<IndraConfigure> call, Response<IndraConfigure> response) {
                    userLiveData.postValue(response.body); //assuming that response.body is of type User
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<IndraConfigure> call, Throwable t) {
                    // do something relevant when call fails to fetch user
                }
            );
        } 
    }

 }
```

Then in your code (preferably ViewModel, using MVVM) when you want to retrieve user from service, do as below:

```
 DataRepository.getInstance().fetchUser().observe() {
  ....
 }
```

And when you just want to use the previously fetched data, do this:

```
DataRepository.getInstance().getUser().observe() {
 ....
}
```

Note that you have to call the `fetchUser()` method at least once before being able to have user data by calling `getUser()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider using `LiveData` with `MVVM` architecture.

## TL; DR

In a nutshell what you're going to do is something like this:

**SharedSessionViewModel**

```
public class SessionSharedViewModel extends ViewModel {


    private LiveData<Session> sharedSession = new MutableLiveData()

    public SessionSharedViewModel() {
        super();
    }

    public void setSession(Session data) {
        MutableLiveData<Session> casted = (MutableLiveData<Session>) this.sharedSession
        casted.postValue(data)
    }
    public LiveData<Session> getSharedSession() {
        return this.sharedSession;
    }
}
```

**FirstFragment**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment() {


    private SessionSharedViewModel session;

    // some sort of callback called when the user session arrives from the API
    public void methodThatHandlesUserData(Session user){
        session.getSharedSession().setSession(user);
    }
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        session = ViewModelProviders.of(this.activity).get(SessionSharedViewModel.class)
        session.sharedSession.observe({yourobservablehere});
        Observer<Session> userObserver = new Observer<>(){
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Session user){observableCallback(user);}
        };
        sharedViewModel.sharedSession.observe(userObserver);
    }
    public void observableCallback(newSession: Session) {
        // Do something when returning to this fragment
    }
}
```

**DetailsFragment**

```
class SessionDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    private SessionSharedViewModel sharedViewModel;

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this.activity).get(SessionSharedViewModel.class)
        Observer<Session> userObserver = new Observer<>(){
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Session user){observableCallback(user);}
        };
        sharedViewModel.sharedSession.observe(userObserver);
    }

    public void observableCallback(newSession: Session) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "This is inside new activity: "+newSession.getUsername(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

---

### Further reading

`LiveData` has been adopted by the Android team it's completely supported by the new `androidx` libraries, forming part of the `Android Arquitechture Components`.

Using `LiveData` provides a nice set of good features like:

- No memory leaks
- The UI of your app matches it's state regarding data
- `LiveData` is life-cycle aware so that means no more crashes due to Activity lifecycle (`ViewModel` <3 `LiveData`)
- Ability of sharing resources between activities and fragments

For even further reading I'd recommend you to go [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#additional-resources)

Comment: I'd gladly use LiveData, but there are a few matters I'd like to avoid. 1 being method count and app size (adding too many libraries), and 2, the fact that my team haven't experienced LiveDate yet. If there is a way to do the same things in RxJava, I'd be more interested in using it.

Comment: I also found PublishSubject, I wonder if that can achieve the same results.

Comment: Haven't used RxJava yet, but it has also been adopted as an `Android Arch. Component`